# Move assignment with base class and derived class

Tags: c++

Below is a downsized implementation of a two classes I'm having trouble with.

#### code:

Here is the base class:

```
//header
class Script
{
public: 
    Script(const QString& path, int timeout=10000) : 
    mPath(path), mTimeout(timeout), script(new QProcess) {}
    Script(Script&& s);
    Script& operator=(Script&& s);
    virtual ~Script();

protected:
    QString mPath;
    int mTimeout;
    QProcess* script;
}

//source
Script::Script(Script&& s) :
    mPath(s.mPath), mTimeout(s.Timeout), script(s.script)
{
    s.script = nullptr;
}

Script& Script::operator=(Script&& s){
    if(&s != this){
        delete script;
        script = s.script;
        s.script = nullptr;

        mPath = s.mPath;
        mTimeout = s.mTimeout;
    }
    return *this;
}

Script::~Script() {
    delete script;
    script = nullptr;
}
```

From the code snippet above I derive the following class:

```
//header
class ConfigurationScript : public Script
{
public:
    ConfigurationScript(const QString& path);
    ConfigurationScript(ConfigurationScript&& s);
    ConfigurationScript& operator=(ConfigurationScript&& s);
}

//source
ConfigurationScript::ConfigurationScript(const QString& path) :
Script(path) {}

ConfigurationScript::ConfigurationScript(ConfigurationScript&& s) : 
Script(std::move(s)) {}

ConfiguratonScript& ConfigurationScript::operator=(ConfigurationScript&& s) {
    if(&s != this){
        delete script;
        script = s.script;
        s.script = nullptr;

        mPath = s.mPath;
        mTimeout = s.mTimeout;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

#### question:

The move assignment of `ConfigurationScript` contains duplicate code when you compare it to the move assignment of its base class `Script`. Can you call the assignment operator of the base class to overcome duplicate code?

For instance is something like this valid?

```
ConfigurationScript& ConfigurationScript::operator=(ConfigurationScript&& s) {
    if(&s != this){
        Script::operator=(s);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The return type of `Script::operator=(s)` is `Script`, do I need to cast it to a `ConfigurationScript`? 
If the above is valid, I fail to see how it works.  Otherwise, is there a way to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's valid, and you don't need to cast anything.

You're not even using the result of the base `op=` call, but you know that it is a `Script&` that refers to the current object. Since you already have a `ConfigurationScript&` that refers to the current object *and* has the needed type (i.e. `*this`), there is nothing more to do.

In fact, this is so natural that you can just let the compiler do it for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Base
{
    Base& operator=(Base&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "YOLO!\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    /*
    // Don't need this
    Derived& operator=(Derived&& other)
    {
        Base::operator=(std::move(other));
        return *this;
    }*/

    /*
    // Or even this (though you may need to introduce it
    // if you have some other user-declared stuff)
    Derived& operator=(Derived&& other) = default;
    */
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1, d2;
    d2 = std::move(d1);
}

// Output: YOLO!
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d8d8c2df29be35))

However I think you probably meant `Script::operator=(std::move(s))` to get true movement rather than a copy.

Comment: Basically, if I have an additional private member in `ConfigurationScript` I can do the following within the move assignment of the same class?

`Script::operator=(s);`
`mAdditional = s.mAdditional;`
`return *this`

Comment: Is it necessary to do `Script::operator=(std::move(s))` since s was already an rvalue reference?

Comment: @BrunoHendrickx Yes you can do that

Comment: @BrunoHendrickx Yes it's necessary because `s` _isn't_ an rvalue reference! Inside the function it's just an lvalue of type `ConfigurationScript`. This is perhaps one of the confusing things of C++, particularly because you would never notice it with a "normal" reference, but it's exposed with rvalue refs.